# Testing Clojure main from REPL

Tags: clojure, program-entry-point, read-eval-print-loop

I have defined a `-main` function in a `:gen-class :main true` namespace in Clojure. I am trying to test it from the REPL.

My `main` function looks like this:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  ; ...
  )
```

and I am trying to call it with `(ns/-main "-x" "foo")`, `(ns/-main "-x foo")`, `(ns/-main ["-x" "foo"])`, `(ns/-main (into-array String ["-x" "foo"])`, etc., and all give me various errors.

How do I call this function from the REPL and pass in some command line arguments to test it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (apply str args)
  )
```

Then called like:

```
(-main "a" "b" "c")
```

And it evaluated to:

```
"abc"
```

As it should..

Be sure to check are you using the right namespace identifier, also see if anything weird is happening inside your `-main` function, like using a string as a number..

Also, it wouldn't hurt to see your error message on this..

Comment: Problem was a DUE (dumb user error). It's working now. Thanks.